# GET 50 average values out of 1000

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Every second I write some data about a current and voltage. I display the data in real time on a chart for a period of 50 seconds, but I'd like to show the data for a longer period of time, for example an hour or two. I'd like to get 50 average points out of this database for the period of an hour. Is it possible to do that in just MySQL, or should I use PHP instead?

This is my SQL structure and some data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Danni` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ustroistvo_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `CurrentA` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ustroistvo_id` (`ustroistvo_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1110 ;


INSERT INTO `Danni` (`id`, `ustroistvo_id`, `data`, `CurrentA`) VALUES
(1, 1, '2013-07-02 10:05:35', 58),
(2, 1, '2013-07-02 10:05:37', 57),
(3, 1, '2013-07-02 10:05:38', 46),
(4, 1, '2013-07-02 10:05:39', 54),
(5, 1, '2013-07-02 10:05:40', 58),
(6, 1, '2013-07-02 10:05:41', 56),
(7, 1, '2013-07-02 10:05:42', 40),
(8, 1, '2013-07-02 10:05:44', 53),
(9, 1, '2013-07-02 10:05:45', 59),
(10, 1, '2013-07-02 10:05:46', 51);
```

Comment: "I'd like to get 50 average points out of this database for the period of an hour" --- please clarify that

Comment: [Welcome to SO, don't forget to **take the SO Tour** it will guide you on how to best use this site](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Comment: Do you want random points over the past hour? Or would you like to average in 72-second increments (72 seconds * 50 = 1 hour)? Also, could you post the table structure.

Comment: I don't have a specific code because i don't know what to do, but the thing is i have 10000 values for some period and i'd like to have the average but not one value but 50 values

Comment: Consider taking advantage of http://sqlfiddle.com/ 
Plus, don't forget to at least skim http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: @EdGibbs I want to have the average in 72-second increments

Comment: if you have a timestamp field you can mod 72 that and select those rows

Comment: @melanholly- please post some sample data and your expected result

Comment: @DevZer0 - rather than `mod`, I was thinking "FLOOR(seconds between now and the reading time, divided by 72)", but I don't have MySQL access today so I can't test - and the query is just involved enough that I don't want to post anything untested. melanholly - if you post sample data and expected results I'll bet you get an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query can look like this:

```
SELECT
    AVG(Value)
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(SavedOn) / 72)
```

SavedOn should be the time you save your Values on.

[Example SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e74a6/1).

Comment: this gives me only one value not 50 and when I change the SavedOn timeStamp i gives me the exact same number as many times as I change it.

Comment: Updated my answer with an example and some explanation.

Comment: i am having trouble understanding your group by, how does this gives records of every 72 interval?

Comment: `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(SavedOn)` gives me time in seconds since `1970-01-01`. Then I divide the seconds by 72 and round those using floor so they get into groups. Let's say I have `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(SavedOn)` returning me 71999, 72001, 72050, 72070, 72090, etc. The function will return 999, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1001 respectively - thus these are the 3 different groups. Let me know if that clarifies what you asked.

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius **Thank you** this is really helpful. It is the thing I was searching for. I cant give you ^ arrow because I am new but again **Thank you**

Comment: Always nice to help :) Good luck :)